# JWT Helper service throws error in Angular 10

Tags: angular, compilation, ivy, jwt

I am working with Angular 10 and the latest JWT Helper service. But the app doesn't compile.

The error states as following:  `ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/lib/jwthelper.service.d.ts`
I've searched for similar issues but couldn't find an answer. It's the first time this happens.

The console also reports the following: `This likely means that the library (@auth0/angular-jwt) which declares JwtHelperService has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy`

I've deleted the node package folder, did `npm i` and the error persists. This means that the Helper Service is not compatible with Angular 10?

My package JSON:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
```

Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me - [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-feovlw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).  if you look at the network tab upon clicking the button, it added the Authorization request header as expected.

According to the library - if you import the JWT Module for root, it will add the authorization headers automatically.  The JWT Helper service is for standalone usage - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt .

Check out the stackblitz link for how I have it working in the angular app

Answer (score 0):

update tsconfig.app.json with:

"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": true
}

Comment: Still error in console  `Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!`